# How to update active item in Listbox headless ui using react query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query, headless-ui

I'm trying to change my active item in a headless ui listbox , the thing is the sidebar items are dynamic and coming from an api and that's making me a bit confused on how to  do it and it's not changing the active item

my code looks like this for the listbox :

```
 <div className={`mt-28 flex flex-col text-center text-4xl font-bold`}>
        {isSuccess && selected && (
          <Listbox value={selected} onChange={setSelected}>
            {/* <Listbox.Button className="mb-2">{selected.name_ar}</Listbox.Button> */}
            <Listbox.Button className="mb-10 flex max-w-[278px] justify-between rounded-31px bg-white py-5 px-[50px] font-inter text-2xl font-bold text-primary">
              <img src={ArrowImage}></img>
              {!isLoading && <span>{selected?.name_ar}</span>}
            </Listbox.Button>
            <Listbox.Options>
              {data?.map((item) => (
                <Listbox.Option
                  key={item.id}
                  value={item}
                  className="hover:text-accent"
                >
                  <Link to={`/${item.id}`}>
                    {i18n.language === "en" ? item.name_en : item.name_ar}
                  </Link>
                </Listbox.Option>
              ))}
            </Listbox.Options>
          </Listbox>
        )}
      </div>
```

my code for the query and the state is :

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState();
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  
  const { data, isLoading, isError, error, isSuccess } = useQuery(
    ["tracks"],
    getTracks,
    {}
  );
```

i'm supposed to be able to add the items coming from the query as the list items , the data shows correctly but the active item doesn't really change .

I tried adding an onSuccess to the react query , but obviously that runs every time the query is run so it's not helpful

any tips ?